# Событие нажатия кнопок на блютуз гарнитуре C#

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно организовать отслеживание кнопок плей/пауза, громкость +/- блютуз гарнитуры? Заметил что в UWP приложениях отслеживание работает (Groove Music в Windows 10). Хотелось бы какой-нибудь пример как это организовано.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В пространстве имен System.Windows.Input есть enum Key, в нём есть клавиши:

MediaNextTrack, MediaPlayPause, VolumeDown, VolumeMute, VolumeUp и т.д.

Соответственно просто при обработке события нажатия клавиши - проверяйте на совпадение с этими.